# @objc redundancy when having @objcMembers private dynamic var?

Tags: swift, realm

So I am using Realm with Swift and I marked my class with the @objcMembers keyword however when I tried to make some private variables, Xcode forced me to add @objc beside those private vars. Is this an intended behavior? Seems like it's redundant to me.

```
@objcMembers class MyObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic private var text: String = String()
    @objc dynamic private var youtubeLink: String = String()
    @objc dynamic private var count: Int = 0
    dynamic var isFavorite: Bool = false
    dynamic var currentCount: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @A.MunzerI added my code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that while `@objMembers` exposes your members to Objective-C, `private` hides them again. Thus, to undo that hiding, you have to say `@objc` explicitly.

To see that this is true, try the following test:

```
@objcMembers class MyObject: NSObject {
    func f() {
        print("howdy")
    }
}
let c = MyObject()
c.perform(Selector("f"))
```

That works. But this crashes:

```
@objcMembers class MyObject: NSObject {
    private func f() {
        print("howdy")
    }
}
let c = MyObject()
c.perform(Selector("f"))
```

To fix the crash without taking away the `private`, we have to expose `f` to Objective-C explicitly:

```
@objcMembers class MyObject: NSObject {
    @objc private func f() {
        print("howdy")
    }
}
let c = MyObject()
c.perform(Selector("f"))
```

The only interesting thing about your particular case is that the compiler *noticed* the problem, instead of letting you just crash as in the second example above. That's because of the `dynamic` marking, which makes no sense unless we are exposed to Objective-C.