# Invoke Swift closure in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to invoke a Swift closure in Objective-C.

There is an error like this even though I declared the function:

> No visible @interface for “User” declares the selector “isReady”

Swift:

```
@objcMember
class User:NSObject {
    func isReady(isTrue: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
User *user = [[User alloc] init];
[_user isReady]. <-  error
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084765/objc-redundancy-when-having-objcmembers-private-dynamic-var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the function [@objc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective-c_code_to_swift) modifier:

```
@objcMember
class User:NSObject {
 @objc public func isReady(isTrue: Bool) -> Bool {
  return true
   }
 }
```

And add public modifier to the function to allow access from other modules (swift code builds as module and ObjC code should export it and access via open interfaces).

Comment: I do not get this  swift code builds as module and objC code should export it and access via open interface

Comment: Just add public to the function and all should works. It is strange, but my Xcode does not allow to use '@objcMember'. I prefer to use '@objc' modifier